# How can I create a Factory that produces objects based on a type or a Class object?

Tags: kotlin, factory

In my Kotlin application I have a few entities (and a data class for each of them) and for each entity I have a service object implementing generic `Service<T>` interface.
I want to create a Factory of services that will return me a proper service based on a parameter which is a type of entity I want to have a service for. In Java I would pass a `Class` object into the factory which I could obtain from a static context of the entity class eg. `Entity.class` but I can't do that in Kotlin. How can I create a Factory that will produce me objects based on a type of an entity?

Comment: Why not? You can do `Entity::class.java`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `KClass`:

Say you have the following classes:

```
abstract class Parent(val name: String)
class ChildA : Parent("A")
class ChildB : Parent("B")
```

Then your factory may look like this:

```
fun <T : Any> factory(c: KClass<T>): T {
     return c.createInstance()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

     val childA = factory(ChildA::class)
     val childB = factory(ChildB::class)

     println(childA.name) // A
     println(childB.name) // B
}
```

But there's a better way using `reified`:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> factory(): T {
     return T::class.createInstance()
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
 val childA = factory<ChildA>()
 val childB = factory<ChildB>()

 println(childA.name)
 println(childB.name)
```

Note that without using `reified` we couldn't do `T::class`